# Particlesjs is causing issues with my landing page. Moving elements around and not sizing properly until manually resized

Tags: html, css, wordpress, particles.js

Good Day,
as mentioned in the title, I am using Vincent Garreau's particles.js library to create a space-themed homepage. It is causing a few issues on my page (I'm not sure whether I'm supposed or allowed to link to it on SO). First, it is moving elements around on load. E.g. I have it displaying in my title section, and it moves any text there is downwards, screwing the page up.
Second, it doesn't actually display in the proper sizes until the page is manually resized. Ergo, it will load a canvas with unusual dimensions until opening, for example, the developer options window, at which point it snaps correctly. Is there a way to get it to load correctly?
Thanks in advance,
Tim

I tried getting particles.js to load on my WordPress website by loading the script and then giving a div the "particles-js" id DOM tag. I was expecting the particles to go into the background and not further interfere with the site. Suffice to say, this didn't happen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.